# Incorrect indexing for max subarray in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I wrote both a brute-force and a divide-and-conquer implementation of the Max Subarray problem in Python. Tests are run by drawing a random sample of integers.

**When the length of the input array is large,** the assert in `__main__` fails because the recursive algorithm does not return the correct answer. However, the two algorithms DO agree when the array is less than 10 elements long (this is approximate, and the actual size of the failed input varies on each execution). The issue does not seem to be related to even or odd array lengths, but it does appear to be related to how the array is indexed.

Sorry if I'm missing something stupid, but why does the recursive algorithm stop returning the correct output when the input array starts getting larger?

```
# Subarray solutions are represented by an array in the form
# [lower_bound, higher_bound, sum]

from sys import maxsize
import random
import time

# Brute force implementation (THETA(n^2))
def bf_max_subarray(A):
    biggest = -maxsize - 1

    left = 0
    right = 0

    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        sum = 0
        for j in range(i, len(A)):
            sum += A[j]
            if sum > biggest:
                biggest = sum
                left = i
                right = j   

    return [left, right, biggest]

# Part of divide-and-conquer solution   
def cross_subarray(A, l, m, r): 
    lsum   = -maxsize - 1
    rsum   = -maxsize - 1
    lbound = 0
    rbound = 0

    tempsum = 0
    for i in range(m, l-1, -1):
        tempsum += A[i]
        if tempsum > lsum:
            lsum = tempsum
            lbound = i

    tempsum = 0
    for j in range(m+1, r+1):
        tempsum += A[j]
        if tempsum > rsum:
            rsum = tempsum
            rbound = j

    return [lbound, rbound, lsum + rsum]

# Recursive solution
def rec_max_subarray(A, l, r):
    # Base case: array of one element
    if (l == r):
        return [l, r, A[l]]
    else:
        m = (l+r)//2

        left  = rec_max_subarray(A, l, m)
        right = rec_max_subarray(A, m+1, r)
        cross = cross_subarray(A, l, m, r)

        # Returns the array representing the subarray with the maximum sum.
        return max([left, right, cross], key=lambda i:i[2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(1, 101):
        A = random.sample(range(-i*2, i), i)

        start = time.clock()
        bf = bf_max_subarray(A)
        bf_time = time.clock() - start

        start = time.clock()
        dc = rec_max_subarray(A, 0, len(A)-1)
        dc_time = time.clock() - start

        assert dc == bf # Make sure the algorithms agree.
```

Comment: Are you sure size has anything to do with it?   `bf_max_subarray` and `rec_max_subarray` don't even seem to agree for `A=[0,1]`.

Comment: I've only inferred as much with the tests I've run. Let me trace with that input and see if I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subarray with the maximum sum is represented by an array of the form `[left_bound, right_bound, sum]`.

But thanks to`return max([left, right, cross], key=lambda i:i[2])`, `rec_max_subarray` returns the correct maximum sum for `A`, but risks returning  indicies that do not match the indicies returned in `bf_max_subarray`. **My error was assuming that the boundaries of a subarray with the maximum sum would be unique.**

The solution is to either fix the criteria that selects a subarray, or just to assert the equality of the sums using `assert dc[2] == bf[2]`.